# MongoDB - most efficient way of getting the last version of a document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm using MongoDB to hold a collection of documents.

Each document has an _id (version) which is an ObjectId.  Each document has a documentId which is shared across the different versions. This too is an OjectId assigned when the first document was created.

What's the most efficient way of finding the most up-to-date version of a document given the documentId?

I.e. I want to get the record where _id = max(_id) and documentId = x

Do I need to use MapReduce?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add index containing both fields (documentId, _id) and don't use max (what for)? Use query with documentId = x, order DESC by _id and limit(1) results to get the latest. Remember about proper sorting order of index (DESC also)

Something like that

```
db.collection.find({documentId : "x"}).sort({_id : -1}).limit(1)
```

Other approach (more denormalized) would be to use other collecion with documents like:

```
{
    documentId : "x",
    latestVersionId : ...
}
```

Use of atomic operations would allow to safely update this collection. Adding proper index would make queries fast as lightning.

There is one thing to take into account - i'm not sure whether ObjectID can always be safely used to order by for latest version. Using timestamp may be more certain approach.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Daimon. Just a question though with regards to second option, if a new record is being inserted into the main document collection, how do you atomically insert and update the denormalised "index" collection? Could another document instance be inserted before the first document's index record is updated?  Does that make sense? You could do a findAndModify right to ensure the document hasn't changed? I guess if it has get the latest _id and try again? Is that the gist?  Thanks again.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support triggers like RDBMS so you have do it application-side. You can use findAndModify to find document with id/timestamp lower then updating one and update it. Because findAndModify is atomic operation it will update document only if new value is really younger then current one - this way you don't have to worry about concurrent updates.

Comment: Thanks again. Assuming I use version number or time stamp, the findAndModfy will fail if another process has added another document instance and updated the "index" document. The findAndModify will try and update the "index" doc where the version is now newer (greater) than the current update. if this happens should I simply get the newest version and try to update the index document again? Sorry if I've repeated anything, just want to get it clear in my mind

Comment: This is for a single result.  Is there something comparable for a range of documents?  `.find({documentId: {$in: [ ... ]}})`

Answer (score 1):

I was typing the same as Daimon's first answer, using `sort` and `limit`. This is probably not recommended, especially with some drivers (which use random numbers instead of increments for the least significant portion), because of the way the _id is generated. It has second [as opposed to something smaller, like millisecond] resolution as the most significant portion, but the last number can be a random number. So if you had a user save twice in a second (probably not likely, but worth noting), you might end up with a slightly out of order latest document.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification for more details on the structure of the ObjectID.

I would recommend adding an explicit versionNumber field to your documents, so you can query in a similar fashion using that field, like so:

```
db.coll.find({documentId: <id>}).sort({versionNum: -1}).limit(1);
```

**edit to answer question in comments**

You can store a regular DateTime directly in MongoDB, but it will only store the milliseconds precision in a "DateTime" format in MongoDB. If that's good enough, it's simpler to do.

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument("dt", DateTime.UtcNow);
coll.Insert (doc);
doc = coll.FindOne();
// see it doesn't have precision...
Console.WriteLine(doc.GetValue("dt").AsUniversalTime.Ticks);
```

If you want .NET DateTime (ticks)/Timestamp precision, you can do a bunch of casts to get it to work, like:

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument("dt", new BsonTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks));
coll.Insert (doc);
doc = coll.FindOne();
// see it does have precision
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(doc.GetValue("dt").AsBsonTimestamp.Value).Ticks);
```

**update again!**

Looks like the real use for BsonTimestamp is to generate unique timestamps within a second resolution. So, you're not really supposed to abuse them as I have in the last few lines of code, and it actually will probably screw up the ordering of results. If you need to store the DateTime at a Tick (100 nanosecond) resolution, you probably should just store the 64-bit int "ticks", which will be sortable in mongodb, and then wrap it in a DateTime after you pull it out of the database again, like so:

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument("dt", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
coll.Insert (doc);
doc = coll.FindOne();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(doc.GetValue("dt").AsInt64);
// see it does have precision  
Console.WriteLine(dt.Ticks);
```

Comment: Thanks wes, you mean like an integer number for the version?

Comment: Using integer counters is possible but it's not scalable at all... use of high resolution timestamp would be better approach - there is always a chance that two documents would share same timestamp - but if it's mission-critical in your case maybe using RDBMS is better approach?

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. It's not mission critical, but obviously needs to work.  Difficult leaving RDBMS concepts behind. Thanks for your input (both)

Comment: @wes +daimon - using the .NET driver, I've declared a DateTime, but having problems representing is as BsonTimestamp. Do either of you have any experience using the .NET driver, and how would I best go about having a Timestamp property. thanks.

Comment: @WesFreeman - thanks! good examples.  I did look at using BsonDocument with DateTime/ticks as described here http://alexmg.com/post/2011/09/30/DateTime-precision-with-MongoDB-and-the-C-Driver.aspx which is similar to how you described although just using ticks is more efficient. Going back to your original proposal of using a versionNumber, would it be best therefore to use a sequence as described here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers - it could be a long (signed 64bit) and even sequenced per entity to give even greater resolution. any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the findAndModify portion to create a "sequence"? I think a timestamp (milliseconds are probably fine if you want to avoid using Ticks) is your best option, as it's simpler (doesn't require two collections). It might not even be necessary (going back to just _id), if you make sure that a particular document isn't versioned more than once per second. If you do want a version number to be a counter, so you can say "this is version 23", the findAndModify they describe in that sequence number section is the way to do it.